# How to pre-populate form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my case, I need a model for such a view:

```
@model EditFormApplication.Models.NewForm

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
}
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field)
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field)
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field)
   <input type="submit" value="save">
}
```

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field)` may be much more, but they are all the same. I do not know what should be the model for this case:

```
namespace EditFormApplication.Models
{
   public class NewForm
   {
       public string Field { get; set; }
   }
}
```

I need to send the filled model to the `Homecontroller`. In the view can be an unlimited number of identical inputs.

Or better fill the model without using `EditorFor()`?

In the controller i just need to get the filled model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditForm (NewForm model)
{
  return View();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  Your model has a single text field, why do you need multiple inputs for the same field?

Comment: @Владислав Контанистов, Please check my answer and let me know if it works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `pre-populate` your `form` you need to set the  model property value in `GET` method as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditForm()
{
   NewForm newForm = new NewForm()
   {
      Field = "Your pre-populate text"
   }
   return View(newForm);
}
```

Now `"Your pre-populate text"` will be shown in every `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field)` in the form.